# getting below error while installing angular CLI through cmd

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting below error while installing angular CLI through cmd

```
**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.t
argets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v14
0') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, either click the Proj
ect menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects..."
. Install v140 to build using the v140 build tools. [C:\Users\prashant\mydata1\n
ode_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]**
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Cool, I would suggest reading the error message and following the instructions in resolving it because it literally tells you what is wrong and gives you suggestions on how to fix it. Good luck!

Comment: To build using the v140 build tools, either click the Proj
ect menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects..."
. Install v140 to build using the v140 build tools